# Posting file with curl as a string

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to upload a file using curl and php with the following code.  I'm passing post data as a string using http_build_query rather than an array because post data is a multi part array.  Code works except I can't get image to upload.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$image=file_get_contents(realpath('image.jpg'));
    $postFields = array(
         'authenticity_token'=>$token1.'=',
         'menu_item'=>array('name'   => $name,
         'body'=>'',
         'published'=>0,
         'published'=>1,
         'picture'=>$image,
    );


        $postData=http_build_query($postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: Can you post your full code ?

Comment: Can you check the answers for these questions mentioned before. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image

Comment: And this one. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584307/php-upload-an-image-file-to-other-domain-with-curl

Comment: Couldn't find an answer to my question in those links... although this comment on the first link might shed some light on my issue:  

"VolkerK is completely right but my experience suggest that sending a file "@" operator will only work with arrays.

$post['file'] = "@FILE_Path"

Now you can send the file using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS"

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure what you want to do. If you want to do normal form posting then remove this below header from your code, and it should work.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
```

Now, if you want to do a `multipart/form-data` posting through curl, then do this:

```
$postFields = array(
     'authenticity_token'=>$token1.'=',
     'menu_item'=>array('name'   => $name,
     'body'=>'',
     'published'=>0,
     'published'=>1,
     'picture'=> '@' . $image, // better to use path like 'c:/temp/image.jpg'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
```

Comment: You are correct in that removing the header did not stop my code from working... still no image uploaded though.  Posting the array without http_build_query doesn't work though and gets me a 400 error as $postFields is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: add this `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` with your code, and show us the Log print by updating your question.

Comment: curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$verbose = fopen('verboselog.txt', 'ab+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_exec ($ch);  ---- adding this code is giving me an empty log

Comment: where did the `verboselog.txt` come from?? check your apache access log, or error log file for the debug messages!

Answer (score 0):

Could not accomplish this using http_build_query on my multi-dimensional post array... the file will not be uploaded by the server.  Had to create the array with the nested part as http does...

```
    $postFields['authenticity_token'=$token1.'=';
    $postFields['menu_item[name]']=$name;        
    $postFields['menu_item[body]']='';
    $postFields['menu_item[published]']=0;
    $postFields['menu_item[published]']=1;
    $postFields['menu_item[picture]']='@'.$image;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
```